# how to pass sbcl a string as a single argument

Tags: bash, common-lisp, sbcl

I want to pass sbcl a string as a single argument using a bashcript but sbcl splits the string into a list.

bashscript

```
#!/bin/bash

    sbcl --noinform --eval "(progn (FORMAT t \"~{~a~%~}\" sb-ext:*posix-argv*)(eval (read-from-string (second sb-ext:*posix-argv*))))" $1
```

execution:

```
>sh bashsrcipt.bs "\"(FORMAT t \"YEAH\")\""
sbcl
"(FORMAT
t
"YEAH")"

debugger invoked on a END-OF-FILE in thread
#<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING {1002999833}>:
  end of file on #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {100443F523}>
```

But the result should have been

```
>sh bashcript.bs "\"(FORMAT t \"YEAH~%\"\")"
sbcl
"(FORMAT t \"YEAH\")"
YEAH
```

The [manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Command-Line-Options) does not mention such behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to quote `$1` in your script, I think:

```
sbcl --noinform --eval "..." "$1"
```

(argument to `--eval` elided for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

`$1` should be enclosed with `""` if you want it to be passed as a single argument when it contains whitespace characters:

```
#!/bin/bash
sbcl --noinform --eval "(progn (format t \"~{~a~%~}\" sb-ext:*posix-argv*) (eval (read-from-string (second sb-ext:*posix-argv*))))" "$1"
```

Moreover, `\"` before and after `(FORMAT ...)` in the command-line argument should be removed, which is making `read-from-string` return a string, not a list, that evaluates to itself. That is, the two `\"`s are preventing `FORMAT` in the argument from being executed:

```
$ sh bashscript.bs "\"(FORMAT t \"YEAH~%\")\""
sbcl
"(FORMAT t "YEAH~%")"
```

```
$ sh bashscript.bs "(FORMAT t \"YEAH~%\")"
sbcl
(FORMAT t "YEAH~%")
YEAH
```